# Que es y para que es el @PostConstruct en java beans?

Tags: java, ejb

En un proyecto/codigo me estoy encontrando con este tag @PostConstruct y no entiendo realmente para que funciona?
Alguien me puede explicar cual es su función  o finalidad.
Se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: En la documentación de oracle está bastante claro: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmgkd.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@PostConstruct
La anotación @PostConstruct define un método como método de inicialización de un bean de resorte que se ejecuta después de que se complete la inyección de dependencia. @PostConstruct es la forma de anotación de init-method que es un atributo de la etiqueta bean. El método @PostConstruct se utiliza para validar las propiedades de bean o para inicializar cualquier tarea. En nuestro bean, debe haber solo un método anotado con @PostConstruct anotación. El método no puede ser estático.

puedes ver el ejemplo que aquí pongo
Book.java

```
package com.concretepage;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

public class Book {
  private String bookName;
  public Book(String bookName) {
    this.bookName = bookName; }

@PostConstruct
public void springPostConstruct() {
     System.out.println("---Do initialization task---");
     if(bookName != null) {
         System.out.println("bookName property initialized with the value:"+ bookName);
     }
}   
public String getBookName() {
    return bookName;
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
package com.concretepage;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration

public class AppConfig {
@Bean
public Book book(){
  return new Book ("Rama");
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Marcas con `@PostConstruct` un metodo que quieras ejecutar en una nueva instancia de tu EJB después de que el contenedor haya resuelto todas las dependencias. Los usos que tienen son muchos, en mi caso lo utilizo para asegurar que ciertos recursos estén disponibles para el EJB antes de llamar a los métodos de negocio.

Answer (score 0):

Es una función que se ejecutará antes que todas las demás.